# Run last playbook even if there was an error previously

Tags: ansible

my test.yaml is something like:

```
---
- name: "PLB1"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: 
       msg: "1"

- name: "PLB2"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - fail:
       msg: "oh no"
      when: 1==1       

- name: "PLB3"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: 
       msg: "2"
```

Is it possible to run PLB3 even if there was an error on PLB2?
(ansible 4.8.0)

Riccardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`fail`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html)_module is for failing the run on condition. Nevertheless it would be possilbe to use [`failed_when: false`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#handlers-and-failure) with it.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: PLB1
    debug:
      msg: "Task 1"

  - name: PLB2
    fail:
      msg: "Failed"
    when: "inventory_hostname == 'localhost'"
    failed_when: false
```

It would result in no message.

```
TASK [PLB2] ***
ok: [localhost]
```

If there should be an message you may use the [`assert`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html)_module.

```
  - name: PLB2
    assert:
      that:
        - "inventory_hostname != 'localhost'"
      fail_msg: "Failed"
      success_msg: "Succeeded"
    failed_when: false

  - name: PLB3
    debug:
      msg: "Task 3"
```

This would result into

```
TASK [PLB2] **********************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false
  assertion: inventory_hostname != 'localhost'
  evaluated_to: false
  failed_when_result: false
  msg: Failed

TASK [PLB3] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Task 3
```